# How to convert a string into array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How to convert "`[{"id":6,"name":"r6","preparation_time":"123","servings":4,"background_media_file":"recipe_background_image","font_color":"#000000","created_at":"2020-09-11 09:27:02","updated_at":"2020-09-11 09:27:02"},{"id":5,"name":"r5","preparation_time":"21","servings":4,"background_media_file":"recipe_background_image","font_color":"#000000","created_at":"2020-09-11 09:26:28","updated_at":"2020-09-11 09:26:28"}]"`

to `[{"id":6,"name":"r6","preparation_time":"123","servings":4,"background_media_file":"recipe_background_image","font_color":"#000000","created_at":"2020-09-11 09:27:02","updated_at":"2020-09-11 09:27:02"},{"id":5,"name":"r5","preparation_time":"21","servings":4,"background_media_file":"recipe_background_image","font_color":"#000000","created_at":"2020-09-11 09:26:28","updated_at":"2020-09-11 09:26:28"}]`

Comment: what is the difference? what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to iterate first one but getting error, recipes.forEach is not a function because it is string, when printed typeof (firstArray)

Comment: How this happened? how you are getting a string like this..

Comment: Trying to access this from laravel blade.php, can't get through api

Comment: Don't you just want `JSON.parse`?

Comment: Yes, it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse()`

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('[{"id":6,"name":"r6","preparation_time":"123","servings":4,"background_media_file":"recipe_background_image","font_color":"#000000","created_at":"2020-09-11 09:27:02","updated_at":"2020-09-11 09:27:02"},{"id":5,"name":"r5","preparation_time":"21","servings":4,"background_media_file":"recipe_background_image","font_color":"#000000","created_at":"2020-09-11 09:26:28","updated_at":"2020-09-11 09:26:28"}]'))
```

Comment: @ShubhamChaudhari : You can accept it as answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

The given string is in json format. By using [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

```js
$arr = JSON.parse('[{"id":6,"name":"r6","preparation_time":"123","servings":4,"background_media_file":"recipe_background_image","font_color":"#000000","created_at":"2020-09-11 09:27:02","updated_at":"2020-09-11 09:27:02"},{"id":5,"name":"r5","preparation_time":"21","servings":4,"background_media_file":"recipe_background_image","font_color":"#000000","created_at":"2020-09-11 09:26:28","updated_at":"2020-09-11 09:26:28"}]');
console.log($arr);
```